# Why getServersideprops return undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I wrote the code to fetch data, but it's show undefined in console.
Here is my code:

```
export default function Home({ data }) {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome !!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10";
  const users = res.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data: users,
    },
  };
}
```

I have to get data in console.

Comment: I'm wondering how that code doesn't throw an error? `res` is a string and a string does not have a `.json()` function... And even if you did something like `res  = await fetch('https...')` you also `res.json()` is async and you would have to `await res.json()`

Comment: please check fetch documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: It's not throwing an error in the console because it'll be throwing an error in the terminal, since the bad code is run serverside

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Home({ users }) {
  console.log(users );
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome !!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
      const res = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10");
  const users = await res.json();

  return {
     props: {
         users 
     }
  }

}
```